# What does 'the timeless' imply in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning

> The very best the Eternal City has to offer, from **the timeless** to new kids on the block, including a next-generation trattoria and a friendly microbrewery. Select your favorites for a perfect weekend away.
>
> [Source: Pick-n-mix Rome](https://pocketmags.com/ca/lonely-planet-traveller-magazine/march-2020/articles/720201/pick-n-mix-rome)

Answer (score -1):

I'm quite sure that it refers to people/beings who don't age,  i.e. are immortal.

It could perhaps  also  refer to those who've been there ever since the founding of the city, as it's eternal.

P.S. What book is this? Reads like something right up my alley.

Edit: Read the linked article, now I bet that it refers to the various buildings, and other architectural fancies.

Comment: https://pocketmags.com/ca/lonely-planet-traveller-magazine/march-2020/articles/720201/pick-n-mix-rome

Comment: It's not particularly ***people / beings***. The actual examples given (though presumably of *new kids on the block*, not "the timeless") aren't even "alive". Although "the poor" always means "poor **people**", the cited use of "the timeless" refers to *anything* (people OR things) that aren't affected by the passage time and/or have been around since the beginning of time.